# Cells formula in tab 1 change their range automaticcaly when i upload data in tab 2

Tags: excel

I am creating an Excel sheet that automatically calculates contamination values.
The sheet has two tabs. The first tab contains the protocol layout for the print-out and some conversion but mostly reads the values from the second tab. The second tab has a connection to call CSVs from a folder, which comes straight out of the measuring device.

The formulas in Tab 1 are mostly just `=IF(Tab2!A40<>0;Tab2!A40;"")`, and they go for a range (about 15 cells). Each subsequent cell will have A40, A41, A42, and so forth.

The first data I uploaded is perfect; all the measurements are correctly displayed, and the blank cells are blacked out.

If I upload another file, either shorter or longer (with one measurement more or less), then the row of cell numbers gets scrambled.

For example, if the first file has five measurements, everything is okay. However, if the second file has four measurements, it will update the first three data correctly, then add a blank (#REF), and then place the fourth measurement in position five.

On the other hand, if the file now has six measurements, it will upload the first four correctly, skip over the fifth, and upload the sixth in the fifth position.

I tried with many different setups and restarted the whole thing more than once.

Does anybody have any idea?

EDIT:
So, I'm more and more convinced that my Excel is malfunctioning.

I tried to work around the problem and found out the problem lies at the root of the file.
Now I have tab1
the only formula in tab 1 is the following
starting in Tab1 A1 I Have `=Tabelle2!E39` (it is in German, sadly)
Then I drag it down a few rows and sideways a few columns.
Nothing else.

In tab 2, I just click on what I think is called "Get External Data" in English. I Browse for more, click the data file, select the spacer, and I'm done.

It already doesn't work...

If somebody wants to have the day ruined:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12_rKyjI-1p4ANHfKhRKpV_FUnhnkqgfX?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you mock up a few tables as examples of the input and then the expected output?  Are you bringing in the .csv data through PowerQuery?

Comment: Use structured (table) references instead of cell addresses.

Comment: So, I'm more and more convinced that my excel is misfunctioning.

Comment: I tried to work around the problem and found out the problem lies at the root of the file.
Now I have tab1
the only formula in tab 1 is the following
starting in Tab1 A1 I Have '=Tabelle2!E39' (it is in German, sadly)
Then I drag it down a few rows and sideways a few columns.
Nothing else.
In tab 2, I just click on what I think is called "Get external Data" in English. I Browse for more, click the data file, select the spacer, and I'm done.

It already doesn't work anymore